# Unexpected token o

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

Im adding an api to check if multiple mcpe servers are online and send it in one message

Ive tried doing it in single messages and it all works

```
'test': async (msg) => {
  request("https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/mcfcraft.xyz", function(errHub, responseHub, statusHub) {
    const bodyHub = JSON.parse(responseHub)
    request("https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/173.249.34.88:25879", function(errFac, responseFac, statusFac) {
      const bodyFac = JSON.parse(responseFac)

      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Server status response")
      .setColor("PURPLE")
      .setDescription("Requested response from our network.")
      if(bodyHub.online === true)  {
        embed.addField("Server: HUB", `Server status: Online\nPlayers: ${bodyHub.players.online}/${bodyHub.players.max}\nMOTD: ${bodyHub.motd.raw}`)
      } else {
        embed.addField("Server: HUB", `Server status: Offline\nPlayers: 0/0\nMOTD: N/A`)
      }

      if(bodyFac.online === true) {
        embed.addField("Server: FACTIONS", `Server status: Online\nPlayers: ${bodyFac.players.online}/${bodyFac.players.max}\nMOTD: ${bodyFac.motd.raw}`)
      } else {
        embed.addField("Server: FACTIONS", `Server status: Offline\nPlayers: 0/0\nMOTD: N/A`)
      }

      msg.channel.send(embed)

    })
  })
}
```

> undefined:1
>   [object Object]
>    ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Request._callback (C:\Users\Gaming Account\Desktop\McfBots\ServerStatus.js:258:28)
>       at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Gaming Account\Desktop\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at Request. (C:\Users\Gaming Account\Desktop\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:197:13)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Gaming Account\Desktop\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:202:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1132:12)

Comment: Your result is already an object, you don't need to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: @str when I put responseFac.body.online it comes out undefined

Comment: @str even when I remove the parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is an object already so there's no need to parse it again. Try doing it like this:

```
const bodyHub = typeof responseHub === 'string' ? JSON.parse(responseHub) : responseHub;
...
const bodyFac = typeof responseFac === 'string' ? JSON.parse(responseFac) : responseFac;
```

This way the result will be parsed only if it's a string.